# Difference between relativistic and non-relativistic classical equations of electron

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrons

Both in classical (non-relativistic) electromagnetism and in relativity the equation of motion of an electron in electromagnetic field is
$$ \frac{d\mathbb{p}}{dt}= e(\mathbb{E}+\frac{\mathbb{v}}{c}\times \mathbb{B}).$$
The momentum $\mathbb{p}$ in the non-relativistic situation is $m\mathbb{v}$, while in the relativistic one it is $\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} \mathbb{v}$. Here $m$ is the rest mass of the electron in both equations.

I am wondering whether the difference between two equations has been detected experimentally for high speed electrons.  (I do not know if that it practically doable due to possible presence of quantum effects.)

Answer (score 1):

Relativistic formula converges to classical one for the low speed also experimental results verifies these relations. Experimentally accelerators can accelerate electrons to reach relativistic speeds relativistic calculations can be verified on the other hand in your question you said is Quantum mechanical limitations causes a problem, actually in wave function analysis, they have similar statistical relation (surely considering uncertainty).

Comment: Do you have a reference regarding relativistic experiments?

Comment: I guess this http://www.sophphx.caltech.edu/Physics_7/Experiment_21.pdf helps

Comment: @MKO also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_relativistic_energy_and_momentum covers more historically detailed experiments where experiments are under the  early experiments section.

Comment: Many thanks! It seems to answer my question.

Comment: @MKO you're welcome.